# Contador de if em um arquivo de texto

Tags: c, c++, contador

Pessoal estou tentando fazer um programa que conta a quantidade de ifs em qualquer texto, mas por algum motivo ele não conta todos, se puderem me ajudar agradeço

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *arq;
    char str[24];
    int count = 0;
    arq = fopen("texto.txt","r+");

    while(fgets(str,sizeof(str),arq) != NULL){
        if(strstr(str,"if") != NULL){
            count++;
        }       
    }

    fclose(arq);

    printf("Qt : %i",count);
}
```

**Conteudo do "texto.txt"**

```
1 if if if if
2 if if if if if if if if
3 if if if if if if if if if if if if
4 if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if
total = 40
```

Quando rodo o programa são exibidos apenas 8.

Comment: Olá, pode compartilhar onde pegou essa lógica? testei seu código e agora lê normalmente, ´mas alterei apenas uma linha e gostaria de entender melhor como esta lógica trabalha.

Comment: Da maneira como declarou sua string `str` você precisa fazer um outro loop para contar em cada string lida. Por exemplo a linha 4 contém 49 caracteres.

Comment: Por acaso a aplicação desse algoritmo seria para se calcular a [complexidade ciclomática](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexidade_ciclom%C3%A1tica) de um determinado código ?

Comment: @anonimo, a resposta para isso é não, vão é necessário.

Comment: @Brewerton: Mas a função `strstr` sempre parte do início da string. No caso do exemplo do post ele conta apenas a primeira ocorrência de cada linha lida, como ele declarou str[24] e existem linhas com mais de 24 caracteres a função `fgets` faz várias leituras de tais linhas. Creio que a função `strtok` é que varia o ponteiro a cada localização.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, mude o tamanho de `str` para 4 e o resultado será como esperado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *arq;
    char str[4];
    int count = 0;
    arq = fopen("texto.txt","r+");

    while(fgets(str,sizeof(str),arq) != NULL){
        if(strstr(str,"if") != NULL){
            count++;
        }       
    }

    fclose(arq);

    printf("Qt : %i",count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Opção percorrendo a string lida:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    FILE *arq;
    char str[255], *p;
    int count = 0;
    arq = fopen("texto.txt","r+");
    while(fgets(str,sizeof(str),arq) != NULL){
        p = str;
        while ((p = strstr(p, "if")) != NULL){
            count++;
            p++;
        }       
    }
    fclose(arq);
    printf("Qt : %i",count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz de uma maneira mais performática em relação a memoria, já que as funções da `string.h` copiam as strings. Em questão de performance não é notório, apenas em arquivos incrivelmente grandes. Eu também não use a lib `string.h`, segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LEN 256

int main() {
    FILE* file;
    char str[256];
    int total = 0;
    const char* strif = "if";

    file = fopen("txt.txt", "r+");

    if (file == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    while (fscanf(file, "%s", str) != EOF) {
        if (str[0] == 'i' && str[1] == 'f' && str[3] == '\0') {
            total++;
            continue;
        } else {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < MAX_LEN - 1; i++) {
                if(str[i] == '\0'){
                    break;
                }
                if (str[i] == 'i' && str[i + 1] == 'f') {
                    total++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Total: %d\n", total);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```